Build Qt 5.15.15 for android, error crtbegin_so.o, ... not found
I need to build Qt 5.15 for android, I am on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64).
I installed all the necessary, android SDK api 31, ndk r21e, ... but I finally get errors about not found android files.
My commande line is:
./qt5/configure -xplatform android-clang --disable-rpath -release -shared -android-arch arm64-v8a 
-android-ndk-platform android-31 -android-ndk /opt/Android/SDK/ndk/android-ndk-r21e -android-sdk 
/opt/Android/SDK -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip webglplugin -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -skip webengine -prefix ./qt5-android-bin

The error is:
Command line: -xplatform android-clang --disable-rpath -release -shared -android-arch arm64-v8a -android-ndk-platform android-31 -android-ndk /opt/Android/SDK/ndk/android-ndk-r21e -android-sdk /opt/Android/SDK -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip webglplugin -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -skip webengine -prefix ./qt5-android-bin
executing config test verifyspec
+ cd /home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/config.tests/verifyspec && /home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/qtbase/bin/qmake "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared warn_off console single_arch" -early "CONFIG += cross_compile" /home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/qt5/qtbase/config.tests/verifyspec
+ cd /home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/config.tests/verifyspec && MAKEFLAGS= /usr/bin/gmake
> /opt/Android/SDK/ndk/android-ndk-r21e/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -target aarch64-linux-android31 -fno-limit-debug-info -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -O2 -fPIC  -I/home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/qt5/qtbase/config.tests/verifyspec -I. -I/home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/android-clang -o verifyspec.o /home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/qt5/qtbase/config.tests/verifyspec/verifyspec.cpp
> /opt/Android/SDK/ndk/android-ndk-r21e/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -target aarch64-linux-android31 -fno-limit-debug-info -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o verifyspec verifyspec.o      -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc
> /opt/Android/SDK/ndk/android-ndk-r21e/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin_so.o: No such file or directory
> /opt/Android/SDK/ndk/android-ndk-r21e/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: cannot find -llog
> /opt/Android/SDK/ndk/android-ndk-r21e/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++
> /opt/Android/SDK/ndk/android-ndk-r21e/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: cannot find crtend_so.o: No such file or directory
> clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> gmake: *** [Makefile:68: verifyspec] Error 1

When I search for the file, for example crtbegin_so.o, it exists but the compiler doesn't search it in the correct folder!
/opt/Android/SDK/ndk$ ls
21.4.7075529  27.2.12479018  android-ndk-r21e


/opt/Android/SDK$ find . -name crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/27/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/30/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/28/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/26/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/22/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/23/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/16/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/18/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/17/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/19/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/24/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/29/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/21/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/27/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/30/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/28/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/26/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/22/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/23/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/16/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/18/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/17/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/19/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/24/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/29/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/21/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/27/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/30/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/28/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/26/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/22/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/23/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/24/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/21/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/27/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/30/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/28/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/26/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/22/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/23/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/24/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/29/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/21/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-26/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-26/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-26/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-26/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-28/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-28/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-28/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-28/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-21/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-18/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-17/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-30/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-30/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-30/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-30/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-29/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-29/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-29/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-29/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-19/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-23/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-23/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-23/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-23/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-22/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-22/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-22/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-22/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-16/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-24/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-24/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-24/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-27/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-27/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-27/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/21.4.7075529/platforms/android-27/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/riscv64-linux-android/35/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/27/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/25/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/30/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/28/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/26/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/22/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/23/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/34/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/35/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/32/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/33/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/24/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/31/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/29/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/21/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/27/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/25/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/30/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/28/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/26/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/22/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/23/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/34/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/35/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/32/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/33/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/24/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/31/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/29/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/21/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/27/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/25/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/30/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/28/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/26/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/22/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/23/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/34/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/35/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/32/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/33/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/24/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/31/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/21/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/27/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/25/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/30/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/28/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/26/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/22/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/23/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/34/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/35/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/32/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/33/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/24/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/31/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/29/crtbegin_so.o
./ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/21/crtbegin_so.o
```

By the way, I don't understand why find doesn't list the files in android-ndk-r21e without searching directly in that folder...

```
/opt/Android/SDK/ndk/android-ndk-r21e$ find . -name crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/27/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/30/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/28/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/26/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/22/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/23/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/16/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/18/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/17/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/19/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/24/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/29/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/21/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/27/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/30/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/28/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/26/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/22/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/23/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/16/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/18/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/17/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/19/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/24/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/29/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/21/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/27/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/30/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/28/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/26/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/22/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/23/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/24/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/21/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/27/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/30/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/28/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/26/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/22/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/23/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/24/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/29/crtbegin_so.o
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/21/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-26/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-26/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-26/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-26/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-28/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-28/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-28/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-28/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-21/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-18/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-17/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-17/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-30/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-30/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-30/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-30/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-29/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-29/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-29/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-29/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-19/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-23/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-23/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-23/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-23/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-22/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-22/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-22/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-22/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-16/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-24/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-24/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-24/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-27/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-27/arch-x86/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-27/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/crtbegin_so.o
./platforms/android-27/arch-arm64/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
```

I found some posts about similar problems, and answers say to create symbolic link but I don't really link that, as I don't think it's normal to modify some existing paths in an installation. Why android or Qt doesn't search in the right folder? Is it a bug?


OK, so meanwhile, I tested with ndk r27 and it succeeds ...
Yet, it is written here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-getting-started.html, that ndk r21 is supported for Qt 5.14 or later.
